# String comparing with wildcards

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, wildcards

I'm trying to check the first and last line of a file to see if it contains a certain string. The file will follow the format

```
HEADER 2016-11-7
...
TOTAL IS:    20938
```

I'm trying to check to see if the first line contains the string `HEADER` then remove it. I have:

```
#get first line of file
header=`head -n +1 rubbish.txt`

echo $header

#If first line contains header, remove it and ouput it to new file
case "HEADER" in
    *"$header"*) tail -n +2 rubbish.txt > rubbish.txt.out
    header="TRUE"
    ;;
    *) echo no HEADER present ;;
esac
```

which outputs:

```
HEADER 10-10-2019                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
no HEADER present
```

Why is it saying that no header is present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have swapped the `word` with the `pattern`; you want something along the lines of:

```
...
case "$header" in
    HEADER*) tail -n +2 rubbish.txt > rubbish.txt.out
    header="TRUE"
    ;;
    *) echo no HEADER present ;;
esac
...
```

Another way to achieve your goal is to use `sed` to delete a header line only if it exists (here using the GNU `-i` extension to edit in-place):

```
sed -i '1{/^HEADER/d}' rubbish.txt
```

A similar example for a potential footer line on the last (`$`) line of the file:

```
sed -i '${/^TOTAL IS:/d}'  rubbish.txt
```

Comment: This works but I'm a little confused. In plain English it's saying `in the case "HEADER 10-10-2019 " is in a string that starts with "HEADER" do this...` shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Wait, it makes sense now that I've written it out in plain English. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrong usage of `case`. Use `if` instead with globbing.

```
if [[ "$(head -n +1 rubbish.txt)" =~ "HEADER" ]]; then
    tail -n +2 rubbish.txt > rubbish.txt.out
else echo no HEADER present
fi
```

Comment: The `=~` operator causes the use of `regex`es not `glob`s.